# Recordset Repeat Regions in 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, repeat, region

I have which shows records from a MySQL database. At the moment I have it set as a table, with a repeat region showing a total of 6 entries.

I'd like this to be repeated to the right, making two columns, ie, one table on the left showing records 1 ~ 6 and one table on the right showing records 7 ~ 12. I'd really value any help you can give... thank you x

My HTML is:

```
<table width="600" border="0">
  <?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_glossary_main['term']; ?>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_glossary_main['definition']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_glossary_main = mysql_fetch_assoc($glossary_main)); ?>
</table>
```

and the php for the page is:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_glossary_main = 6;
$pageNum_glossary_main = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_glossary_main'])) {
  $pageNum_glossary_main = $_GET['pageNum_glossary_main'];
}
$startRow_glossary_main = $pageNum_glossary_main * $maxRows_glossary_main;

mysql_select_db($database_ships, $ships);
$query_glossary_main = "SELECT * FROM glossary_main ORDER BY term ASC";
$query_limit_glossary_main = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_glossary_main, $startRow_glossary_main, $maxRows_glossary_main);
$glossary_main = mysql_query($query_limit_glossary_main, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row_glossary_main = mysql_fetch_assoc($glossary_main);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_glossary_main'])) {
  $totalRows_glossary_main = $_GET['totalRows_glossary_main'];
} else {
  $all_glossary_main = mysql_query($query_glossary_main);
  $totalRows_glossary_main = mysql_num_rows($all_glossary_main);
}
$totalPages_glossary_main = ceil($totalRows_glossary_main/$maxRows_glossary_main)-1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your all result in array

```
$resultrow=array();
while ($row_glossary_main = mysql_fetch_assoc($glossary_main))
  {$resultrow=$row_glossary_main; }
```

count the total number of array $resultrow

then where you have to output

```
$count=count($resultrow)/2;
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
     {
       <td>$resultrow[$i]</td><td>$resultrow[$count*2-1]</td> 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, so I put the array code at the end of my php section in the header do I? For your output do I completely replace my original output or integrate it somehow. THank you for your help

Comment: that's brilliant, what would you do with your output code then?

Comment: @user2406993 sorry man i can code write now ,i am going to sleep now,now its midnight in india.